# Android SettingsActivity, how to trigger BackButton

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-settings

The application i'm developing will run on a tablet which is going to be placed inside a "cage" to prevent the user from removing it.
This "cage" will recreate a Kiosk mode; the android buttons Bar with the back and the home button will not be physical accessible by the user.

In the Main activities and in the fragment i managed to "go back" by calling onBackPressed() within the OnClickListener of some buttons.

Now the problem is that i have to add a settings activity, this kind of activity doesn't use normal layouts but PreferenceScreen instead.

I can't figure out how to action onBackPressed() if the only things that i can show in the layout are the prefereces.

I tryed adding a switchpreference called GoBack and creating an handler with refresh continuisly and check if GoBack preference is True, in that case i would set it to false and i would trigger onBackPressed(); but it didn't work, Go Back didn't change, the app crashed and i wasn't able to make it working.

Here's the SettingActivity code (The android studio one)

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {


private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();


        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    try {
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try {
            sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                    PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                            .getBoolean(preference.getKey(),false));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Impostazioni","Impossibile eseguire Sett.Binding di "+preference.getKey());
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("PassWordImpostazioni"));
        //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        /*bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("LedBattutaPorta"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("SpoilerPosteriore"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("LuciBianche"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("Scalino"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("Webasto"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("Stufa220V"));*/


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Here's the PreferenceScreen XML

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPT. Luci"
    android:key="OptLuci">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="LedBattutaPorta"
        android:title="Pulsante Disabilitazione Led Battuta Porta" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="SpoilerPosteriore"
        android:title="Pulsante Disabilitazione Spoiler Posteriore" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="LuciBianche"
        android:title="Pulsante Disabilitazione Luci Bianche" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPT. Servizi"
    android:key="OptServizi">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Scalino"
        android:title="Pulsante Disabilitazione Scalino" />

</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPT. Clima"
    android:key="OptClima">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Webasto"
        android:title="Webasto" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Stufa220V"
        android:title="Stufa 220V" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPT. Vano Sanitario"
    android:key="OptVanoSanitario">

    <SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="Bombola1"
    android:title="Presenza Bombola 1" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Bombola2"
        android:title="Presenza Bombola 2" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Did you try creating your custom preference ?

Comment: Does your design let you use a ToolBar? or ActionBar?

Comment: I don't have experience and time to create a custom preferece activity, that's why i'm applying some modifyes to the android studio one.

Comment: The main activity is pinned and fullscreen, i don't have any action bar or toolbar. When i enter in the settingactivity it isn't pinned anymore, but actually i don't have any toolbar or actionbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in this way:

I made another custom theme just for the settings in which i show the action bar with the back button.

It works fine, thanks to everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a button and in the click of the button, call:

```
finishActivity();
```

This will force a return to previous activity in your activity stack.

Comment: I can't add a button in this kind of layout, becouse it isn't actually a layout  but a ScreenPreference which allow you only some components like SwichPreference or TextPreference. I can't manage the OnClick event too in this kind of activity

Comment: Use PreferenceFragment (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) in your settings activity, and I think you can also use preference change listeners in your current state but that would be too dirty..

Comment: I'm trying to use PreferenceFragment, do you know how to call the Fragment Replacement with this kind of frag? I can't handle the transaction like i was doing with normal fragments

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.preference_container, fragment, SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();

Comment: If you want to just make it work, add a switchPreference to go back and in you preference change listener finishActivity() if that switch is toggled true

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()  doesn't work with Preferences fragments, it requires a Fragment. Anyway the actionbar wasn't visible becouse the MAin Theme was NoActionBar, so i made another custom theme just for the settings in which i show the action bar with the back button. I've tryed aaaaand problem solved! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**1.Back Button in Activity**

Copy the layout from

**com.android.internal.R.layout.preference_list_content_single**

Add your back button and overwrite the onCreate to set your new layout

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(yourLayout)

}
```

**2.Back Button in Fragment Layout**

Copy the layout from

**com.android.internal.R.layout.preference_list_fragment**

And add your back button

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TypedArray a = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(null,
                                                        com.android.internal.R.styleable.PreferenceFragment,
                                                        com.android.internal.R.attr.preferenceFragmentStyle,
                                                        0);

    int yourLayout = R.layout.your_layout; //put your custom layout here
    yourLayout = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.PreferenceFragment_layout,
                                   yourLayout);

    a.recycle();

    return inflater.inflate(yourLayout, container, false);
}
```

Register an OnClickListener to the button and call onBackPressed() of the Activity which will trigger the back action (finish() will destroy the activity, which might not be useful if you want to navigate back to an earlier fragment)

Edit: I haven´t tested it, but it should work